# After updating Google Ads SDK onAdFailedToLoad is deprecated, How to resolve?

Tags: android, admob, banner-ads

After updating Google Ads SDK to 19.3.0 gives a deprecated warning message for `onAdFailedToLoad()`. How can I resolve this?

My code:

```
public void BannerAdMob() {
        final AdView adView = findViewById(R.id.adsView);
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int error) { // this method is deprecated 
                
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They added a new method you should override instead of that one:

`public void onAdFailedToLoad (LoadAdError adError)`

You can get a bunch of information from the `adError` object, calling `getCode()` on it will give you the code that the old method had.

Answer (score 4):

please refer [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/ad-load-errors) for more info.
the complete example as below:

```
    @Override
public void onAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError error) {
  // Gets the domain from which the error came.
  String errorDomain = error.getDomain();
  // Gets the error code. See
  // https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest#constant-summary
  // for a list of possible codes.
  int errorCode = error.getCode();
  // Gets an error message.
  // For example "Account not approved yet". See
  // https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9905175 for explanations of
  // common errors.
  String errorMessage = error.getMessage();
  // Gets additional response information about the request. See
  // https://developers.google.com/admob/android/response-info for more
  // information.
  ResponseInfo responseInfo = error.getResponseInfo();
  // Gets the cause of the error, if available.
  AdError cause = error.getCause();
  // All of this information is available via the error's toString() method.
  Log.d("Ads", error.toString());
}
```